# Create new flutter project giving an error, "flutter SDK is not found"

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create new Flutter project using VSCode, it gives an error

> "Could not find a Flutter SDK. Please ensure flutter is installed and in your PATH (you may need to restart). "

Comment: iam not facing issue with code , its just while iam creating new flutter project , it shows the message i mentioned about PATH.

Comment: i tried to locate the PATH and rebooting but still doesn't work.

Comment: What platform are you using? Mac/linux/windows? What installation steps did you follow?

Comment: windows , i followed flutter.dev installation for windows.

Comment: i created two simple projects yesterday, but when i opened it today it tells "flutter SDK is not found".